# If Statement - Is this a string?

Tags: python, string, list, function, types

I have several dictionaries set, each with the same keys and different definitions.

Trying to write a function that determines if the key's definition is a string or a list.

Keeps printing nothing...

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students = [lloyd,alice,tyler]

def compute_grades(ourstudents):
    for item in ourstudents:
        if item["name"] == type(str):
            print "YES"

compute_grades(students)
```

How do I use an if statement in this case to determine IF it's a string or IF it's a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isinstance`:

```
>>> isinstance("foo", str) #Use basestring in py2.x
True
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], list)
True
```

Comment: Let's give it a whirl

Comment: I wonder... is isinstance for future end development when all sorts of things change?

Comment: if isinstance(item, str) == True:

Comment: @NicholasHazel Just using `str` will not handle unicode strings in py2.x

Comment: @NicholasHazel `item` is `dict` in your case, so, `isinstance(item, str)` is going to be `False`.

Comment: Hmmmm, I see what you mean... so I should write another for loop? Or is there an easier way to target all keys in a dictionary in a single line?

Comment: @NicholasHazel looping over a dict returns it's keys: `for key in item`. There's `dict.items()` too, that returns both key and value: `for key,value in item.items()`

Comment: Thank you. I'll play and interactively approach it to learn the concept. Much appreciated

Comment: you may want to compare the type against basestring instead of str to also get correct answers for unicode strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
if item["name"] == type(str):
```

There's two things wrong with this:

- you're comparing the *value*, not the type, of the "name" field
- you're comparing it to the type of `str`; `str` *is itself* the string type, so `type(str)` is the type type, as you can see here:

  ```
  >>> type("Alice")
  <type 'str'>
  >>> str
  <type 'str'>
  >>> type(str)
  <type 'type'>
  ```

From this, you can see that `"Alice" == type(str)` must be false.

The preferred way to check types in python, if you need to, is to use `isinstance(<value>, <type>)`; for example:

```
>>> isinstance("Alice", str)
True
```

Comment: if isinstance(item, str) == True:

Comment: As `A == True` is true if A is true, and false if A is false, the expression `A == True` is the same as `A` for boolean A's.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `type` to the other argument of the comparison.

```
if type(item["name"]) == str:
```

Comment: GJ. So, is isinstance different from type?

Comment: @NicholasHazel: Yes. `isinstance` also checks if the object is of a derived class.  Comparing with `type` checks if it is an instance of the exact same class.

Comment: .. very well put sir. Thank you